# Align divs in groups and show a header for each group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to add a header `div` on top of each group of machines. See the image below.

```css
.group {
  display: inline;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #008040;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 75px;
}

.machine {
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: red;
  height: 75px;
  width: 50px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 3px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="group1" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group2" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>

<div id="group3" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine">1</div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine">2</div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine">3</div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine">4</div>
</div>
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

[Click to see the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VG3N.png)

Comment: **1st**; what have you tried so far?? **2nd**- image is not enough you can post the expected code not the expected image .. **3rd**- why you can not do it in your html file directly instead of using js??

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hnwy4s7f/

Comment: If you want javascript to take care of creating the new div element you can always trying using something like this... https://jsfiddle.net/43kfrvna/

Comment: Also I don't recommend having duplicate ID's `subdiv1`... and all other subdivs

Comment: Thank you @NewToJS! That's almost it, but I need group 3 to start immediately after group 2 (as in my example of the initial code)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using pseudo-element `before`:

```css
.group {
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #008040;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.group::before {
  content: attr(data-header);
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(38, 38, 255);
  color: white;
  line-height: 2;
}

.machine {
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: red;
  height: 75px;
  width: 50px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.machine span {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="group1" data-header="group1" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine"><span>1</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine"><span>2</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine"><span>3</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine"><span>4</span></div>
</div>

<div id="group2" data-header="group2" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine"><span>1</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine"><span>2</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine"><span>3</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine"><span>4</span></div>
</div>

<div id="group3" data-header="group3" class="group">
  <div id="subDiv1" class="machine"><span>1</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv2" class="machine"><span>2</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv3" class="machine"><span>3</span></div>
  <div id="subDiv4" class="machine"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Anurag! That's almost it, but I need group 3 to start immediately after group 2 (as in my example of the initial code)